# Currying returns "... is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I try to curry a function, which I define in a class `someClass` like this:

```
class SomeClass extends AnotherClass {

   _someFunc(arg1) {
        const foo = arg1.map(bar => {
            return function(arg2) {
                bar[arg2];
            }
        });

        return foo;
    }

   yetAnotherMethod() {
      ...
      somenewFunc()
   }

    someMethod()
        ...
        const someNewFunc = this._someFunc(someVar)("abc");
        ....

 }
```

In the same class, I have a method `someMethod()` where I try to calll my

When I start my App I get

> this._someFunc(...) is not a function

Why is that?

Comment: `arg1.map`.. so is `someVar` an array?

Comment: have you tried accessing the function without `this`?

Comment: Maybe the context changes? Also someFunc returns an array of functions so you cant call it...

Comment: Where is `this._someFunc(someVar)("abc");` called from?

Comment: foo is an array not a function.

Comment: an array of functions @James

Comment: @suraj an array of whatever

Comment: Does it say "*`this._someFunc(someVar)` is not a function*" or "*`this._someFunc` is not a function*"?

Comment: `foo` is an array of functions. You cannot call that.

Comment: @Berg `this._someFunc(...)`

Comment: @Stophface Then your error is wrong.  There is no way `this._someFunc` is not a function (unless you are calling `someMethod` with a different context)

Comment: the result of thing.map is always an array.  so as it is, _someFunc will always return an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do:

```
const someNewFunc = this._someFunc(someVar)[0]("abc");
```

SomeFunc returns an Array. This will take the first function out of that array and calls it.
If you want to get all values in an array, may do:

```
   _someFunc(arg1,arg2) {
    return arg1.map(bar =>bar[arg2]);
  }

const someNewFunc = this._someFunc(someVar,"abc");
```

Or if you want it to be a function:

```
_someFunc(arg1) {
 return function(arg2){
    return arg1.map(bar =>bar[arg2]);
 }
}

const someNewFunc = this._someFunc(someVar)("abc");
```

Comment: @Stophface youve changed your code... Its neccessary  to use this in your newest version...

Comment: @Stophface check if your `someVar` has some value and not an empty array.